# Is there any way to use FutureBuilder(future) inside the initState on this situation?

Tags: flutter, dart

Below `FutureBuilder` using on the `ListView`. `findRequirement` base on item of `ListView`. This `FutureBuilder` on inside `Build` method. But office document said **"The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during `State.initState`, `State.didUpdateConfig`, or `State.didChangeDependencies`."**

Problem is every time scrolling calling to the `findRequirement` api and Now listView is slow/lag.

```
 ListView.builder(
     ...
     itemCount:value.length,
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
     ...
     FutureBuilder<List<RequirementModel>>(
          future: db.findRequirement(
                 userId, value[index].subCategoryId),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                       //widget
                 } else
                       return Container();
    })
```

Comment: use [MapCache](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/quiver.cache/MapCache-class.html) for example

Comment: @pskink is it possible to use with `FutureBuilder`? can you give me an example?

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jPxJtZCdqD/

Comment: @pskink this is working perfectly. thank you very much

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: @pskink if you have time, can you check this? https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/whQTvRSsBS/ and also I used `maximumSize: 200` size. is it okay?

Comment: I clear map https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/WyRS9RRr5S/

Comment: what's your problem with that code?

Comment: code is working. is it enough size? maximumSize: 200

Comment: I don't know, it depends on how many items fit one screen

Comment: okay thanks I got. 200 mean, 200 items right? Thank you for your time

Comment: @pskink I think your way is good, but I have a ListView and listview has a search option. the search result doesn't match with map-cache(index). data doesn't match with the current index. So. I every time clear CacheMap. and call API unnecessary time.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```dart
// inside state class
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future _getRequirments;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getRequirments = db.findRequirement(
                 userId, value[index].subCategoryId);
  }
  
  
 // change your FutureBuilder to this
  FutureBuilder<List<RequirementModel>>(
          future: _getRequirments,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                       //widget
                 } else
                       return Container();
```

this way it won't keep on calling your method again and again because you only get the future once which is inside `initState()` and `FutureBuilder future:` has that state and doesn't call the `db.findRequirement(userId, value[index].subCategoryId);`
for each build.

Comment: this one is wrong. how do you capture `value[index].subCategoryId` on `initState`?

Comment: i am not sure what you want, but i am sure my answer is the correct way of obtaining a state from an async method without causing it to be called for each re-build, you can take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYN46233cws) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for try to help. I know this way, that's why I mention my title **.on this situation**. need listView item value to call to the api. that's why I used it. `db.findRequirement( userId, value[index].subCategoryId);`  this is listView item `value[index].subCategoryId`. I hope you can understand it